# Thymeleaf not interpreting sec tags

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, thymeleaf

I've ran into an issue where thymleaf is not recognising the sec tag in my spring boot project. e.g. the below the sec:authentication is not being intepreted and appears as is in the html in the browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head th:replace="fragments/header"> </head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
            Roles <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div th:replace="fragments/footer"></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

From reading around i need the following dependency, which I've added to my project.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

But still no luck. The above dependency seems to be the solution for most people, any ideas what else i could be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be a few things that might not be set correctly. Anyways, this issue tend to always resolve by adding missing dependencies or changing the ones you are using. So, first, try changing to `springsecurity5`. And add the following `@Bean`.

**Configuration**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;

@Configuration
public class LeafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect(){
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

}
```

**POM**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, if you are using `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>`, don't add any version to your Thymeleaf Extras, let Spring Boot manage that for you.

Comment: Thanks upgrading to thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5 fixed it.

Comment: Glad I could help :)