# Thymeleaf sec:authorize tag is not working with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot project with Thymeleaf and in memory authentication. In my html I want to display the logout (odjavljivanje in serbian) button only when somebody is logged in.
I tried different suggestions from this site but none came up with a solution.

[thymeleaf sec:authorize not working in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197139/thymeleaf-secauthorize-not-working-in-spring-boot)

[Thymeleaf not interpreting sec tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53559877/thymeleaf-not-interpreting-sec-tags)

This is thymeleaf configuration:

```
package digitmain.config;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public SpringWebConfig() {
        super();
    }



    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/webjars/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/webfonts/**",
                "/fonts/**",
                "/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/",
                        "classpath:/static/images/",
                        "classpath:/static/css/",
                        "classpath:/static/webfonts/",
                        "classpath:/static/fonts/",
                        "classpath:/static/js/");

    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setCacheSeconds(-1);
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames(new String[]{"i18n/Global", "i18n/Pretrazivanje", "i18n/Digitalizacija",
                "i18n/webnibis"} );
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver  templateResolver(){
        // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
        // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver  templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver ();
        //templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
  //      templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
       // templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
        // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;        

    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }



    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/anonymous.html");

        registry.addViewController("/login.html");
        registry.addViewController("/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/console.html");
        registry.addViewController("/csrfHome.html");
        registry.addViewController("/search.html");

    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("sr").setRegion("RS").build();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(locale);        
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect(){
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

}
```

And this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>digitmain</groupId>
    <artifactId>digitmain</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>digitmain</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jcache.version>1.0.0</jcache.version>      
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
             <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is security configuration:

```
package digitmain.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("admin").password("{noop}password").roles("ADMIN");

    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {       
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/webfonts/**", "/fonts/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/korisnici/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .usernameParameter("user")
        .passwordParameter("pwd")        
        .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler());

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
        return new DgSearchAuthCuccessHandler();
    }
}
```

html fragment that does not work:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-right">
                    <li>
                        <a th:href="@{/index}" th:text="#{pocetna.stranica}">Home page</a>
                    </li>                   
                    **<li sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">**
                        <a href="/webnibis/korisnici"  th:text="#{prijavljivanje}" >Prijavljivanje</a>
                    </li>
                    <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                        <a href="/webnibis/korisnici"  th:text="#{odjavljivanje}" >Odjavljivanje</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

Tag sec:authorize is shown as written. Whether or not the user is logged in, both links are displayed (prijavljivanje, odjavljivanje).

Any idea?

Comment: Did you define the tag in your HTML?  `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"`

Comment: Yes, I defined this tag.